# How to get the value of the next two cells to the current selected cell which is selected in a combobox?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have 3 columns:

```
    A1 Breed           B1 Animal  C1 Color
    A2 Poodle          B2 Dog     C2 Grey
    A3 German Shepherd B3 Dog     C3 White
    A4 Munchkin        B4 Cat     C4 Calico
```

I display the values of the first column in a combobox using the following code:

```
Function OppNameCheck()
'Select cell A2, *first line of data*.
  Sheet1.Range("A2").Select
  ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
  With ComboBox1
  Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
  'Add the value of the selected cell to the Combobox list
        .AddItem ActiveCell.Value
     ' Step down 1 row from present location.
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Loop
  End With
End Function
```

What I want to do is after selecting a value in the combobox, the 2 values in the cells next to the selected value are displayed in textboxes.

Example:

Combobox values is populated with values from Column A and value selected is German Shepherd. I want the two text boxes to be populated with Dog and White.

How do I do this?

Comment: The two values from the cells or the two items of the combobox?

Comment: @jivko I want the two values of the cells to be displayed in the text boxes. I edited the question to include examples. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have two textboxes named TextBox1 and TextBox2, then try this...

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim r As Long
If ComboBox1 <> "" Then
    r = Application.Match(ComboBox1.Value, Sheet1.Columns(1), 0)
    TextBox1.Value = Sheet1.Range("B" & r)
    TextBox2.Value = Sheet1.Range("C" & r)
Else
    TextBox1.Value = ""
    TextBox2.Value = ""
End If
End Sub
```